# Eclipse GEF model editor perform drag and drop

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drag-and-drop, eclipse-gef

I working on Eclipse plugin and i need to perform drag&drop support to editor. Editor is a canvas with several EditParts. I need: when user drop (one editpart/several selected editparts) on another editpart, system detect it and determine all models of editparts and do some code. 
As I undestand, I should use polices (some subclass of XYLayoutEditPolicy), but I cant catch event, when user drop part/parts.
I need help. Thanks.

Comment: I found, that when i override getAddCommand method in XYLayoutEditPolicy, i can catch when user drag elements on other element. But still cant catch drop event and cant determine target.

Comment: Just resolved. Simply override getAddCommand method. EventTarget - is host. You can get it by getHost() call. No need to cath event - just create command, it will be executed when need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just resolved. Simply override getAddCommand method. EventTarget - is host. You can get it by getHost() call. No need to cath event - just create command, it will be executed when need.